# Question regarding Givens Rotation

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I need to solve the following equation using Givens Rotation:

$$
A\cdot x = b
$$

**Correction: I need to solve:**

$$
||A\cdot x - b || \to \min
$$

with
$$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 &  1 \\
 -2 & -7 \\
  0 & -5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$b=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
{-13 \over 2} \\
{-5 \over 2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Using Givens Rotation I get to the equation:
$$
Q^T\cdot A\cdot x = Q^T \cdot b
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   -2.2361 &  -6.7082 \\
         0 &   5.4772 \\
         0 &        0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   -6.2610 \\
    3.1038 \\
    0.8165 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The numbers are from matlab, but they are the same as the exact results on my paper. But I don't understand the last row. There it says:

$$ 0 \cdot x_1 + 0 \cdot x_2 = 0.8165 $$

What am I missing here?

Ignoring the last row, and using back substitution I get the same results for $x_1$ and $x_2$ as I did with solving $A^TAx = A^Tb$.

Comment: Since $Ax=b$ cannot hold for any $x$ if $b$ is not in the range of $A$, $Q^TAx=Q^Tb$ cannot hold for any $x$ either. Recall, that you want to solve $\|b-Ax\|=\min_x$ instead of $Ax=b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimizing $\|Ax-b\|$ is equivalent to minimizing $\|Q^T(Ax-b)\|$. This norm is minimal if 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   -2.2361 &  -6.7082 \\
         0 &   5.4772 \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   -6.2610 \\
    3.1038 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
thus ignoring the third row of your system. Let $\hat x$ be the solution of this system.

Then the third row gives you the residual in the equation:
$$
\|A\hat x - b\|= 0.8165.
$$
This is the minimal residual you can obtain, any other vector $x$ will yield a larger residual.